# How to format this NSString correctly?

Tags: objective-c

I want to format a string that can look like that:

```
0.0580 which means 5.8 ct

0.1580 which means 15.8 ct

1.1580 which means 1.15 €
```

So the string can be anything in `x.xxxx` format. Now I started formating it but I am new to objective-c and iOS.

First I want to remove the last character because the last number does not really matter and I don't want to round numbers.

```
NSString *responseString = [responseData 
                    substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 
                             [responseData length]-2)];
```

This gives me x.xxx so far. Any idea how to proceed and what code to use? Are there any libraries on that?

Comment: Is the value coming from a float or NSNumber object? Because will be coding will be different.

Comment: Reading your question again, do you want to extract the number from the string?

Comment: No I don't want to convert it into integer (well it was not my aim), I just want to format the initial string so that the user understands that I want to display money, 0.0580 into 5.8 ct...

Comment: My middle school teacher would certainly disagree that 1.1580 would round to be 1.15 €. It would be correctly rounded to 1.16 €, correct? This is truncation vs arithmetic rounding. So do you want to truncate or round the number? What would 0.0088 be for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the NSNumberFormatter class.  It should do what you need.  Something like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[@"0.158" doubleValue]]; 
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *formattedValue = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber];
[numFormatter release];
```

Also look at NSNumberFormatterStyle and NSNumberFormatterBehavior to control the format.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your number in the form `x.xxx`, you could do something like:

```
float floatValue = [@"0.158" floatValue]; // Get your string as a number.
floatValue *= 100; // Turn '0.158' into '1.58'
```

Does this answer your question? I'm not quite sure that it does, so update your question and I will try to assist you better.

Comment: intValue actually returns 0 when I log it

Comment: Not surprisingly, since `(int) 0.158` is indeed 0... Try `float value = [@"0.158" floatValue];`. Although I'm not sure that really answers your question either.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD & walkytalky:  =(  Good catch. I realllly need a weekend.